# Incorrect data in SSRS Reports

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

My reports are getting the data from cube. I refreshed the cube everytime when I have to use that cube or that report.

The problem is I am getting the required data in cube, but in some part(some columns) of the reports its getting the wrong data.

For example from cube I am getting the data A,B,C, D,E,F,G (these are the measures) & x,y,z are the dimensions  I am using in the cubes.

In reports there are three columns TEST1, TEST2, TEST3.

TEST1 has an expression (sum(A)/sum(B))

TEST2 has an expression (sum(C)/sum(D))

TEST3 has an expression (sum(E)/sum(F))

I am getting the right data for TEST1 & TEST2 but not for TEST3.

What could be the reason. I have checked all the expressions. There is no problem with the expression.

Is there anything else besides the refreshing of the cube. Means refreshing of the reports on server?

Thanks,

Shashra

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have just refreshed the cube and and asked my dba team to refresh the reports on server also. As they refresh the reports on server reports working fine and should check the box is related to itself or it is connect to some other box. If it is connect to some other box then the output may vary.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS caches the original dataset when previewing report. After you deploy the report, the data being reported will be correct.